# salesforce lightning this.template.querySelector not working

Tags: salesforce1-app

```
<template>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
            <div if:false={loggedIn} class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <span>Login to Salesforce App</span>
                    <lightning-input name='username' label="Username"></lightning-input>
                   <lightning-input type="password" name='password' label="Password"></lightning-input>
                   <br/>
                   <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Login" title="Login" onclick={login}></lightning-button>
           </div>
</div>
</template>
  login() {
        console.log('login attempt');
        console.log(this.template);
         var Username =this.template.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value;
        var Password =this.template.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
        console.log(Password);
        console.log(Username );
}
```

values are not getting fetch in username, password variables. `this.template.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value` is not working.

I have also tried onchange event approach on lightning-input elements, in that case, `event.target` was `undefined`? I am stuck not able to read user input.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the **name** attribute is not placed on the lightning-input element but on the internal input element.

Instead, you can add data-attributes to your input elements.

Then you can use `this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-anyName=anyValue]").value` to get the entered text.

Here is a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/5Yj4ErkNN/4/edit) to visualize this.

```
<template>

    <div if:false={loggedIn} class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <span>Login to Salesforce App</span>
            <div>
                <lightning-input data-username='username' label="Username"></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input type="password" data-password='password' label="Password"></lightning-input>
                <br/>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Login" title="Login" onclick={login}></lightning-button>
            </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    loggedIn = false;
    username = '';
    password = '';


    login() {
        this.username = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-username]").value;
        this.password = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-password]").value
        console.log("Username>> ", this.username);
        console.log("Password>> ", this.password);
    }  

}
```

Or another approach. Here is the [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/5Yj4ErkNN/5/edit)

```
<template>

    <div if:false={loggedIn} class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <span>Login to Salesforce App</span>
            <div>
                <lightning-input data-field ='username' label="Username"></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input type="password" data-field ='password' label="Password"></lightning-input>
                <br/>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Login" title="Login" onclick={login}></lightning-button>
            </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    loggedIn = false;
    username = '';
    password = '';


    login() {
        this.username = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='username']").value;
        this.password = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='password']").value;

        console.log("Username>> ", this.username);
        console.log("Password>> ", this.password);
    }  

}
```

Comment: event.target is undefined for me.

Comment: here is a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/5Yj4ErkNN/2/edit). Try to enter a username and password and click on the Login button and look in the console

Comment: @Ajay do you still have a problem?

Comment: yes, its not working yet...event.target is undefined.

Comment: @Ajay Kelkar,  I updated my answer adding more explanation